# asp.net jquery validation return false

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have jquery code to validate.

```
function deneme() {
var url = document.getElementById('ctl00_PostitPanel_frmPostAc_txtLink').value;
var youtubeUrl = url.match(/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
var vimeoUrl = url.match(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(clip\:)?(\d+).*$/);
if (youtubeUrl) {
    return true;
}
else if (vimeoUrl) {
    return true;
}
else {
    alert('Şimdilik Sadece Youtube ve Vimeo videolarını paylaşabilirsin.');

    return false;
    }

   };
```

This codes working great.But I want to prevent insert event.It is showing alert.But then inserting item.And code behind.(My controls inside formview.It is not important.Because function working.)

```
 Button btnKaydet = (Button)frmPostAc.FindControl("btnKaydet");
        btnKaydet.Attributes.Add("onclick","deneme();");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
btnKaydet.Attributes.Add("onclick","return deneme();");
```

Note that I have added `return` before the function call. If the function returns `false`, it should not post back

Comment: It worked for a once.But for example I write valid link and then inserted.And then I wrote invalid value but inserted too..

Comment: when page is postback it is working.Postback needed everytime ?

Comment: This is how it should behave http://jsfiddle.net/gqvM4/ Try changing the url variable value

Comment: you are right.I think there is problem in my codes.Your answer was right for my question.Thanks